# Replace all non-intersecting values with 0, between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mask

Say I have a multi-dimensional array, for example:

```
a = array([[[86, 27],
    [26, 59]],

   [[ 1, 16],
    [46,  5]],

   [[71, 85],
    [ 6, 71]]])
```

And say I have a one-dimensional array (`b`), with some values which may be seen in my multi-dimensional array (`a`):

```
b = [26, 16, 6, 71]
```

Now I want to replace all of the non-intersecting values in array `a` with zero. I want to get the following result:

```
a = array([[[0, 0],
    [26, 0]],

   [[ 0, 16],
    [ 0,  0]],

   [[71, 0],
    [ 6, 71]]])
```

How could I achieve this?

I tried several ways of coding which didn't work. I expected the following line to work, but I think there is an issue with using `not in` in this format:

```
a = np.where(a not in b, int(0), a)
```

I get the following error when I try this:

```
arr = np.where(arr not in required_intensities, int(0), arr) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am unsure what to try next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.isin()` is perfect for this:

```
a[~np.isin(a, b)] = 0
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [26,  0]],

       [[ 0, 16],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[71,  0],
        [ 6, 71]]])
```